# Calling function template for a derived class from a base one

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, types

I have `Consequence`, `Event` and `EventsConsequences` classes.
Each `Event`'s derived class has the list of `Consequence` objects that it triggers stored in `EventsConsequences` object. If two `Event` objects are of the same type (class) then they must trigger the same `Consequence`s.

So in `EventsConsequences` class I have:

```cpp14
unordered_map<std::type_index, std::vector<Consequence*>> consequences;

template<typename Event>
void add_trigger_of(Consequence *consequence) {
    consequences[typeid(Event)].push_back(consequence);
}

template<typename Event>
void trigger_consequences_of(Event *event) {
    for (Consequence *consequence : consequences[typeid(Event)]);
        consequence->react_to(event);
}
```

In `Event` class:

```cpp14
EventsConsequences* consequences;

void trigger() {
    consequences->trigger_consequences_of(this);
}
```

And, of course, I have many derived classes of both `Event` and `Consequence`.

What I want is for it to work, but it doesn't. It always calls

```cpp14
EventsConsequences::trigger_consequences_of<Event>(Event*)
```

But not of a derived classes.

The only idea I have to fix this is to make `Event::trigger()` `virtual` and for every derived class override it

```cpp14
void DerivedEvent::trigger() override {
    consequences->trigger_consequences_of(this);
}
```

But I hate writing WET code. Are there any other ways of doing it?

Comment: So, you want to achieve polymorphism (_"What I want is func() to be dependent on class type"_) but don't want to use the built-in tools for doing polymorphism?

Comment: Why are you trying to make a virtual function (dynamic polymorphism) call a template (static polymorphism)? Do you actually gain anything from having the template be separate? Does it do anything different for the different types? If yes, why can't you just put that different stuff directly in the virtual function implementations, not in the template? You should probably describe what you're trying to do, not how you're currently trying to do it, as this may well be an x/y question.

Comment: @underscore_d Edited my question.

Comment: IMO if you have to use `typeid()` then it's usually an indication that your design could use a rethink. I don't immediately have a replacement to suggest, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `type_index` of the dynamic type of the object rather than the `type_index` of the type template argument to access the map.

```
consequences[typeid(*event)]
```

Just make sure that `Event` has at least one virtual function.

Answer (score 3):

Use the curiously recurring template pattern ([CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)):

```
template <typename Derived>
struct Base {
    void foo() {
        func(static_cast<Derived*>(this));
    }
};

struct A : Base<A> { };
struct B : Base<B> { };

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.foo();
    b.foo();
}
```

Comment: Note: the question looked considerably different when I wrote that answer.